# I just want to print pyramid only using for loop in php as like as the give image

Tags: php

My code is

```
<center>
<?php

    for($i = 0; $i < 7 ; $i++) {

        for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
            echo "*";
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
<center>
```

But I want is pyramid with useing `<center></center>` html tags.

Comment: 1) Which image ? 2) What is the problem/question ?

Comment: The *given image* being... ?

Comment: HTML <center> tags are so deprecated I think they won't even work anymore.

Comment: I cannot submit my question properly ...MY question is i just want pyramid only using for loop  php. Not useing <center></center> tag in html.

Comment: I'm sorry but if you can't submit your question properly, it's only natural you won't have a proper answer. I suggest you read a lot more about PHP - HTML parsing, current valid markups and PHP loop logics, there are plenty of tutorials over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this:

```
<div class="text-center"><!-- or however you choose to center this -->
<?php
$w = 7;
for ($n = 0; $n < $w; $n++) {
    echo str_repeat("-", $n) . "<br>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   int k =0;
   for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
      for(a=1;a<=20;$a++){
         echo "  ";
      }   
      while(k!=(2*i-1){
         echo "* ";
         k++;
      }
      k=0;
      echo "\n";

   }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks every one who are contribute with my problem.But still i didn't get right ans.